# VideoJS - autoLoad subtitle

Tags: javascript, video

How do I load the subtitle automatically?

```
<video id="filme" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="760" height="427" poster="img/teaser-tutorial.jpg" data-setup="{}">
        <source src="videos/tutorial.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        <track src="videos/tutorial.srt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en-US" label="English"></track>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gee, I just got videojs to autoload captions in Chrome on Windows desktop and iPad and Safari on iPad.

To the code above my changes were:

```
<track src="videos/tutorial.vtt" kind="captions" srclang="en-US" label="English" default></track>
```

i.e. - used .vtt file, not .srt, named them `captions` (not `subtitles`) and added `default` at the end of the `track` tag). The only meanginful change, it looks like, was `default`, although maybe `.srt` isn't supported